# Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to two `CGAffineTransform` operands

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift2

I am trying to compare transform value like this but there is a compiler error

> Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to two `CGAffineTransform`
>   operands

```
if view.transform == CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1) {
    //DO SOMETHING
}
```

How do we compare the scale?

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a function to compare transforms:

```
CGAffineTransformEqualToTransform(view.transform , CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1))
```